# How to disable the grey background colour on iterm2 desactived tab split?

Tags: macos, iterm2

In iterm2, by default setting, only the current using tab split will have the normal black background colour, meanwhile all the other tab splits will be covered by a fog-like grey background colour.

I know this may be designed to improving concentration. The problem is, sometimes I really need to view two splits at the same time. And this fog-like grey background colour has increased the difficulty of reading.

Is there some way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 117):

I found it by myself.

Click the `iterm` button on the top bar, select `Preferences`, then click `Appearance` icon, on the right part of the panel, Under the `Dimming` options, there is a `Dim inactive split panes` option, you cancel the default selected status, done!

Answer (score 22):

Thanks for Zen's answer, screeshot may be more clear:
[image: picture]